# What happens when a task expires

Tags: approval-process

I have a workflow with dynamic approvers, with duration per task set to 1 day. When approvers open the task form, they only see Reassign  and Cancel buttons, no Approve or Reject buttons.

Is the duration per task the culprit here?

What happens when we cross the "duration per task" and/or the "due date" apart from email notifications.